# Trying to get my Rails Api to run through HTTPS on EC2 instance in AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-security-group

I have successfully gotten my SSL certificate and configured the load balancer but I can't start the server to run through HTTPS. I have tried to run the rails server by running "rails s -p 443 -b 0.0.0.0"  which is the port for the HTTP requests as seen in the security group but I get permission denied response in the terminal. I just want to understand the proper way to start my server so it runs through HTTPS.

Comment: so do i just start the server with "rails s -p 3003 -b 0.0.0.0"  which is the HTTP port I configured from the security group then enter the IP address? Its really confusing

Comment: its on an EC2 instance

Comment: I have the same issue. What solution did you find?